# Конвертация List в Map

Tags: java, java-8, lambda

Есть такой клас:

```
public class Anima{

  public List<String> name;
}
```

Хочу поместить все name с Animal в Map<String, Integer>. Есть имя но хочу указать уникальный ид.

Как написать в Java 8 вот такое, условие класс Animal нельзя менять:

```
for(int i = 0; i < animal.name.size(); i++) {
    mapOfAnimal.put(animal.name.get(i), i);
}
```

Comment: Если ид уникально, может оно и должно быть ключем?

Comment: @tym32167 проблема в том что ид я должен указать сам, хотелось бы написать for как в Java 8, но не знаю как зделать ключ уникальным тогда

Comment: Что значит «как в джава 8»?

Comment: @tym32167 использование стримов\лямбда

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В случае, если нужно просто воспроизвести Вашу логику используя `Stream API`, то код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
package com.somepackage;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

public class Main {

    @Builder
    @Getter
    public static class Animal {
        public List<String> names;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var animal =
                Animal.builder()
                        .names(List.of("Cat", "Dog", "Hamster"))
                        .build();
        var result =
                IntStream.range(0, animal.getNames().size())
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(
                            toMap(
                                    i -> animal.getNames().get(i), 
                                    i -> i));
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Результат:

```
{Cat=0, Dog=1, Hamster=2}
```